# I can't implement the so-called pixel lighting in the 2d game on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am creating a 2D unity game and my idea was to make pixel lighting. that is, as you approach the lantern, the objects will change color (according to the color palette).
the effect I want to get is shown below (this is a drawing so far).
I have no idea how such "lighting" can be implemented, at first I thought to do it using shader graph, but out of my stupidity I could not do it. (I tried many more options, but I never managed to implement my plans) for this, I ask for help from those who know.

[image: lighting example]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with 2d lighting, so I'm not certain, but I have an old post processing shader that can pixelize and use a limited color pallet for the default render pipeline that might work for you.

Shader:

```
Shader "Custom/PixelPallet"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ColorTheme("Theme", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _ColorTheme;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            int _PixelDensity;
            float2 _ScreenAspectRatioMultiplier;
            float2 _SpriteAspectRatioMultiplier;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float2 pixelScaling = _PixelDensity * _ScreenAspectRatioMultiplier;
                float2 pixelCoord = round(i.uv * pixelScaling)/ pixelScaling;
                fixed4 value = tex2D(_MainTex, pixelCoord);
                float2 coord = float2(value.r,value.g);
                return tex2D(_ColorTheme, coord);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Post Process Script:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class PostEfect : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Material mat;
    public Texture texture;
    public int pixelDensity = 80;

    void Start()
    {
        mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/PixelPallet"));
        mat.SetTexture("_ColorTheme", texture);
    }

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
    {
        Vector2 aspectRatioData;
        if (Screen.height > Screen.width)
            aspectRatioData = new Vector2((float)Screen.width / Screen.height, 1);
        else
            aspectRatioData = new Vector2(1, (float)Screen.height / Screen.width);
        mat.SetVector("_ScreenAspectRatioMultiplier", aspectRatioData);
        mat.SetInt("_PixelDensity", pixelDensity);

        // Read pixels from the source RenderTexture, apply the material, copy the updated results to the destination RenderTexture
        Graphics.Blit(src, dest, mat);
    }
}
```

Just drop the script on the camera and select a color pallet sprite with point filter. Adjust the pixel Density according to your needs.

Comment: thank you very much!!! I'll check right away